# Orchard CMS: User activity logging

Tags: logging, orchardcms

Is there a nice way of logging / monitoring user activity in Orchard CMS 1.4?

Comment: It would be great if you'd mark my answer as answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to monitor and how you want to see the results (log file, e-mail...).

E.g. with the Rules engine it's pretty simple to fire events if something happens with content items (created, published, removed...) and e.g. send an e-mail accordingly. If the existing actions aren't sufficient for you you could create a new one (like for the mentioned logging: AFAIK there's no action that writes a message to the log file).

Also by hooking into the various events Orchard services expose you could write start with something from code.

Also you may update to 1.6 :-).